# How to find the minimum value in tableau?

Tags: calculated-columns, calculated-field, tableau-api

How to find the minimum value, and display one employee?

[image]

```
ID         | employee  | MIN
-----------+-----------+--------------------
IM32837253 | employee1 | 10.11.2016 20:48:40
           | employee2 | 10.11.2016 20:10:40
```

I want to achieve that the result displays the following

```
ID, employee, min (time)
IM32837253, employee2, 10.11.2016 20:10:40
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should consider that Dates are recognized as **dimensions**.

That being said, to get the minimum value for a certain combination of dimensions (all in the row shelf), you just right click your date field then click measure and then minimum.

Take a look at the example using the superstore dataset with Order date as your time field.

[image]